# prop("checked",false) not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with a bunch of checkboxes and a whole bunch of JS fires when you check/uncheck them.  The problem is that if you check a few boxes, submit the form and then hit the back button, your browser leaves the checkboxes checked, but none of the other JS fires like it would if you clicked to check the boxes.

My half @ssed solution was to have the form on load uncheck all checkboxes. That way the user would have to re-check the boxes and all the JS would fire.

unfortunately the code I'm using to uncheck the boxes works in Chrome, but not IE11. In IE11, hitting back results in the checkboxes still being checked. Is there something else I should be doing?

```
          $("input:checkbox").prop("checked",false);
```

Comment: Do you wait for onDocumentLoad event?
http://jsfiddle.net/e04tjbef/

Comment: have you tried attr()

Comment: Please post a complete code example.